# Simple rails button question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Very noob question here.

I am trying to make a digg-like website and when they click a button I want a counter to go up, just like in digg. So I did:

```
 <%=button_to("vote", :action => "vote")%>
```

and then in my controller I made a action:

```
def vote
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.votes = @article.votes + 1
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(@article.company) }
  end
end
```

When I do that you I get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"agree", :controller=>"companies"}
```

What should I do?

Comment: the routes.rb and the file names for controller and views would help here.

Answer (score 4):

In a terminal type "rake routes", then look at your routes to find what path you need to use to vote for an article.

Then use

`<%= button_to "Vote", vote_path(:id => article.id) %>`

Just change the "vote_path" to the path in your rake routes output.

If it's not already in your rake routes file, put something like this in

```
match "vote/:id" => "controler_name#vote", :as => :vote
```

Comment: Good answer Solomon!

@GabeJacobs, you should read up on what routes are for. Any routing error implies that you either haven't specified the route yet or are using it incorrectly in your code. Info about your view and controller along with your route would us to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: so I did "resources :companies do
      get 'agree'
  end" and I still get the same error